# Draw text on screen

Tags: ios, text, draw

I keep it short: I am looking for a way to simply draw text (something like that: `drawTextOnScreen:(NSString)stringToDraw at:(CGPoint)point` on the screen just like drawing a line with for example:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y+innerRadius)]; //lower
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y+outerRadius)];
```

I really cant find an easy solution for an easy task like that.

I am targeting iOS8

Comment: Use a core animation path layer and animate that.

Comment: can you explain this a bit more? I dont even know what to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am using this solution now. Thanks to InkGolem for the small hint. This code writes the string "textOnScreen" to the position x=75 and y=35 with yellow colour.

```
UILabel *uiLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 15)];
uiLabel.text = @"textOnScreen";
uiLabel.frame=CGRectMake(75, 35, 160, 20);
uiLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0];
uiLabel.textColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
uiLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:uiLabel];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want an easy way to draw a string, use `UILabel`.

If you have to use core graphics you could use `[NSString drawInRect: withAttributes:]`.

Comment: I am using `AVCaputreSession` for the camera. And I like to show this text as an overlay to the actual cameraview. Is this possible when using `[NSString drawInRect: withAttributes:]` ?

Comment: Just add a UILabel as a subview of the CameraView.